# how do you get iOS 4 sdk with the new XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I downloaded XCode and it only has the iOS 5 sdk

How do you get the iOS 4 sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html if you must have the older sdk's

Comment: I must, I'm following the nerd ranch book and nothing in the new xcode matches

Comment: and to think I considered signing up for the dev program and dropping $100 on a venture that that's where the download was. ha ha

Answer (score 2):

It's included; you just need to configure your project's Base SDK so it builds against iOS SDK 4.

Comment: then why don't I get the old template selection?

Comment: The old templates aren't part of the SDK; they're part of the old version of Xcode. The new templates should work with iOS 4, as long as you avoid using storyboards and the new APIs.